# Relative file path in folders in tsconfig.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ubuntu-16.04

I have created root folder as "TypescriptProgramming" in which my tsconfig.json resides. There is another folder called "chapter1" containing another folder named "minfunction". The minfunction folder contains "minfunction.ts".  I'm working with typescript version 1.8.10 and nodejs version 6.5.0 on Ubuntu 16.04.

The project structure is as below(tsconfig is outside chapter1 folder):

[image]

When I'm compiling project, it's giving me error **error TS6053: "chapter1/minfunction/minfunction.ts" not found**. Can anyone please let me know where I am going wrong? And what I am missing?

Comment: You've stated in your question that the file is named `minfolder.ts` and the error claims `tsc` is looking for `minfunction.ts`.

Comment: @cartant thanks for pointing out. It was typo. I've corrected it in question above.

Comment: You should include in your question the content of your `tsconfig.json` and also the directory in which you are running `tsc` (that is how you are compiling it, right?) and the command line you are using.

Comment: @cartant Added image. command line is tsc for compiling on "Tyepescriptprogramming" folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operating system you are using has a case-sensitive file system and the case in your file/directory names is not consistent: `MinFunction` is spelled `Minfunction` in the `tsconfig.json`.